# Getting 404 error at the time of edit using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Here, I am inserting record using ckeditor and uploading an image using ckeditor.
When I am going to insert an image at the time of adding, I can upload image using kcfinder.
At that time I am getting link proper to insert image like, ( When I get link as `http://localhost/project/ABC/policies/add`)

```
http://localhost/svn_project/PMS/resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

But, when I want to edit that record to upload an image, it shows worng url like, (When I get link as `http://localhost/project/ABC/policies/edit/2`)

```
http://localhost/svn_project/PMS/hr_policies/resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

In config.js of ckeditor,

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

So, What should I do at the time of edit, that I can upload an image.?

Answer (score 3):

I think it may have to do with the way you specified your URLs in your configuration.

You have...

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
```

Instead, try listing it from the root of your site. Assuming that your "resource" folder is in the root of your website, it would be...

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
```

Make that change for each of your config URLs (config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl, config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl, etc...)

Good luck!
Tom

Answer (score 0):

May be the error of the paths in config.php.

Path relative to the document root (that part after domain name).

$Config['UserFilesPath'] = '/files/' ;
Absolute server path to the same directory above
$Config['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = "/home/login/public_html/example.com/files/";

Note:
$Config['UserFilesPath'] = 'http://example.com/files/' ;
is ok.

but:
$Config['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = "http://example.com/files/";is wrong.